# Как скрывать bottom navigation view в определённых фрагментах, если используется паттерн single acitivity?

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view, single-activity

У меня есть приложение с разными экранами: несколько экранов на которых не нужна bottom navigation view, такие как ввод номера телефона, редактировать профиль, о программе и т.д., и есть три окна на которых навигация нужна, такие как контакты, переписка и настройки программы. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы навигация отображалась только на тех экранах где она нужна, если при этом используется паттерн single acitivity?

Была идея скрывать навигацию в фрагментах где она не нужна

```
final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = getActivity();
    if (fragmentActivity != null) {
        fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Но мне кажется, что этот код слишком небезопасный + когда навигация скрывается, то остается пустое место вместо неё.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу вашего решения, чтобы не оставалось свободного места используйте не `INVISIBLE`, а `GONE`. Тогда лайаут будет пересчитан так, как будто `GONE` вьюшек вообще в нем нет, а `INVISIBLE` он размещает так же как и все,  просто не отрисовывает

Я бы сделал следующее:

1. Создаем некоторый `MyFragment`, о которого наследуются вообще все ваши фрагменты
2. в этом MyFragment создаем абстрактный метод, возвращающий `boolean`,
   допустим `boolean needNav()`. Для тех фрагментов, которым нужна
   навигация, этот метод возвращает `true`, для тех где нет - `false`
3. в вашем активити должен быть метод, который отвечает за смену
   фрагментов. Назовем его `void next(MyFragment fragment, int flags)`.
   У вас не должно быть такого, что во всех фрагментах создаются
   транзакции. Ваши фрагменты должны вызывать функцию активити next,
   передавая в параметра то, какой фрагмент показать и кучу прочих
   параметров, вроде использовать ли анимацию или класть ли текущий
   фрагмент в стэк, через флаги или отдельные параметры. И уже внутри
   функции next вы вызываете для полученного фрагмента `needNav()` и
   скрывается/показывается ваш bottom navigation view